# Notepad++ on CSV Regex select only text between HTML tags STRONG

Tags: html, regex, csv, tags, notepad++

How on Notepad++ in a CSV file I can use Regex to select only text between HTML tags STRONG

### I intend to convert this:

```
"<ul>
<li><strong>488590-131</strong> (prateado)</li>
<li><strong>502622-131</strong></li>
<li><strong>506796-131</strong> (prateado)</li>
<li><strong>AEQT6T00110</strong></li>
</ul>"
"<ul>
<li><strong>455MKL32L01</strong></li>
<li><strong>749650-001</strong></li>
</ul>"
"<ul>
<li><strong>361316-006</strong></li>
<li><strong>389952-001</strong></li>
</ul>"
```

---

### Into this:

```
488590-131
502622-131
506796-131
AEQT6T00110
455MKL32L01
749650-001
361316-006
389952-001
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You can replace everything else with the matching group (containing only the required characters).

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/ajdyzx/1)

[Updated Regex101 demo2](https://regex101.com/r/ECdHOq/2)

I am not sure why it isn't working in notepad++ but working correctly in Atom (see images below)
[image: Matching everything with capturing groups]

[image]